# IE9 has slow UI response on Javascript / JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

Are there more people who have experienced a big javascript/JQuery performance problem in IE9? 
Like menus, etc and for example the Accordion control (Ajax control toolkit).
I think this is unacceptable. And I really think MS is going the wrong direction with this new JS-Engine.
Maybe I'm missing something, but right now I'm thinking of quiting my job as a developer. This is not funny anymore.

Comment: I am currently working on a site that is basically pure jquery with loads of UI and it works fine in IE9

Comment: @user I was relieved to see my jQuery/jQuery UI projects loading and operating much faster in IE9 beta and RC1 actually...

Answer (score 2):

I found out what's causing the problem! And yes, it is (still?) a problem in IE9, though not that big of one.

IE9 can't handle elements with a CSS filter/shadow very well, like:

```
filter: Shadow(Color=#ffffff,Direction=135,Strength=1)
```

You run into issues when you apply this filter to elements handled by JavaScript/jQuery. The funny thing is that the overall performance of the whole web page is going to be really poor as a result.

I hope MS is working on that.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't IE9 still in development? I
One version of Google Chrom in development had a massive javascript problem with simple javascript functions taking over 20 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is IE9 that is causing performance problem. I ran [Sputnik](http://sputnik.googlelabs.com/) test suite on IE9 and according to the tests it has best JS engine out there among all till now. IE 9 Beta failed 83 tests and Chrome 9 failed 130 tests. Reason to believe IE9 this time is that exhaustive tests are of google. :D